# Chars above 127 won't convert properly to Byte

Tags: c#, arrays, string, encoding, casting

I noticed a strange behavior, chars above 127 will not convert properly into Byte. It's a well known problem but I can't understand why it happens. I found out about it when I was working on a client-server app. The thing is chars are unsigned and so are Bytes so where is the loss of data

```
public class Constants
{
     public constant char TOP3_REQUEST_CODE = (char)148;
}

public void printTopThree()
{
    string request = Constants.TOP3_REQUEST_CODE.ToString();
    string response = SendAndRecive (Constants.PORT, Constants.IP, request, Globals.SOCKET);
    //The rest isn't relevant.

public string SendAndRecive(string port, string ip, string request, Socket socket)
{
    Byte[] bytesSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
    Console.WriteLine(request [0]);
    Console.WriteLine(bytesSend[0]);
    //The program continues but its not relevant.
}
```

The code afterward doesn't change the byte array or string so it can't affect the results.

The output is:
148
63

The first char in the request is the code of the message (happens to be 148) but after converting, the first byte is 63.

My questions are:
1. How I can fix this? Is there some kind of another encoding that may solve my problem?
2. Why does this thing happen anyways?

EDIT: The request looks like this (in general):
1st byte: (char) Code (20,100,148 etc...)
2nd - 4th bytes: (int) Length (the length of the JSON object, The length can be 1, 2, or 3 bytes long)
5th - X bytes: (char) JsonObject (It's converted to char[])

Thanks for your time and attention
    - Anthon

Comment: A [mcve] (including the inputs to the method) would be awesome.

Comment: ASCII table goes only up to 127, are you sure you are receiving ASCII content?. You can check it http://www.asciitable.com/ Check the encoding of the data received, UTF8, Unicode, ASCII, there are lots of them

Comment: When `request` is a string,  then `request[0]` should not be 'a code'. It sounds like you are mixing / confusing text and bytes, with ASCII as another questionable assumption.

Comment: The thing is I'm sending the request via a socket the request looks like this:

Comment: Code, length, data

Comment: The data is json and this is why I used string from the get go.

Comment: JSON should be sent as UTF-8, not as ASCII. Make sure both sides agrees on encoding.

Comment: Your string has most likely been encoded, check [Character Encoding in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding).

Comment: Can you explain why? Thank you in advance. I just want to learn and understand.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen most likely OP is dealing with UTF8 without knowing. That would explaiin values above 127. Anthon, check the Unicode/UTF8 table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 and see if it matches what you are dealing with

Comment: Required reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Thank you @bradbury9 you are correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: JSON is *defined* to be encoded with UTF-8, it is *required* by the standard, that is, when you're transporting JSON between services, storing it, etc. From [RFC 8259](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259): "JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8". Granted, if you are *in* a closed ecosystem you have more leniency, but you should still adhere to this rule unless you have a VERY specific reason not to.

Comment: Thank you @John Wu ! I'm reading it right now.

Comment: "Code, length, data" use [edit] to add that to the question and try to be specific about the datatypes. Are `Code` and `Length` bytes or ints?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you,
@Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen and @Marc Gravell♦ where right,
Use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Strings and characters in C# don't use single-byte encodings. You should use the unicode encoding the CLR uses under the hood:

```
Byte[] bytesSend = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(request);
```

Comment: This only works if both sides of the transport pipe agrees on the encoding. If the other end is expecting (or sending) ASCII, this will not work.

Comment: Thank you @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen! Your solution works. Unicode seems to crash the server because of a vector error but UTF8 works flawlessly. So thank you very much sir. Have a truly wonderful day!

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is little-endian UTF-16 It is almost unheard of to see UTF-16 these days (unless it is talking to an API that was designed back during the unicode wars); and since OP mentions ASCII, *if* we're going to talk above that range, UTF-8 should usually be the next thing to check